# div events after the html_insert using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am replacing html of div with some value

> $('.class').html('')

Now I wish to trigger an event once the html is change

So i tried with `$('.class').bind('change',function)` i didnt get a success. 
Please suggest me the proper way

Answer (score 1):

Triggering should be as easy as `$('.class').html('').trigger('myevent')`

Answer (score 0):

You can just call you function after you do this line

```
 $('.class').html('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you change html in your script, you could use a `trigger` to raise your own event.

```
$('.class').html('')
$('.class').trigger('htmlChanged')
....
$(otherSelector).bind('htmlChanged', data, function(){ do stuff });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hook HTMLChange event to .html() like this:

```
jQuery.fn.html = (function(){
var old = jQuery.fn.html;

    return function(){
        var args = [].slice.call( arguments );
    this.trigger( "HTMLChange", args );
    return old.apply( this, args );
    };


})();
```

Then:

```
$('.class').bind('HTMLChange', function( e, newHTML ){
console.log( newHTML + " is new html for " + this );
});

$(".class").html( "sup" );

//sup is new html for [object HTMLDivElement]
```